# Get a smooth contour out of a width-variant shape?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a polygon comprising of 5 edges. Each edge has **its own width**, which is randomly generated between 0.2 and 0.5 here for illustration purpose.

## Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.path import Path

import math as mt
import random

def buildRectPath(edge, width):
    theta = mt.atan((edge[1][1]-edge[0][1]) / (edge[1][0]-edge[0][0]+0.0000001)) # avoid ZeroDivisionError
    x_left_top = edge[0][0] - mt.sin(theta) * width
    y_left_top = edge[0][1] + mt.cos(theta) * width
    x_left_bottom = edge[0][0]
    y_left_bottom = edge[0][1]
    x_right_top = edge[1][0] - mt.sin(theta) * width
    y_right_top = edge[1][1] + mt.cos(theta) * width
    x_right_bottom = edge[1][0]
    y_right_bottom = edge[1][1]
    verts = [(x_left_bottom, y_left_bottom), # left, bottom
             (x_left_top, y_left_top), # left, top
             (x_right_top, y_right_top), # right, top
             (x_right_bottom, y_right_bottom), # right, bottom
             (x_left_bottom, y_left_bottom),] # ignored
    codes = [Path.MOVETO,
             Path.LINETO,
             Path.LINETO,
             Path.LINETO,
             Path.CLOSEPOLY,]
    path = Path(verts, codes)
    return path

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
axes.axis('equal')
poly = [(1, 1), (2, 4), (4, 6), (6, 6), (8, 3), (1, 1)] # construct a random polygon
# expand each edge of the polygon (to different widths)
edges = [[(1, 1), (2, 4)], [(2, 4), (4, 6)], [(4, 6), (6, 6)], [(6, 6), (8, 3)], [(8, 3), (1, 1)]]
widths = [random.uniform(0.2, 0.5) for cnt in xrange(5)] # generate random widths for the 5 edges
for i, edge in enumerate(edges):
    axes.plot([edge[0][0], edge[1][0]], [edge[0][1], edge[1][1]], color='b')
    rectPath = buildRectPath(edge, widths[i])
    rectPatch = patches.PathPatch(rectPath, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
    axes.add_patch(rectPatch)
```

## Output

[image]

## Goal

**I want to get a smooth contour of the shape.** Basically, I am expecting two curves, one for inner loop and the other for the outer loop.

**Note that**

- Since the widths of the lines are different, the  contour that I am looking for is kind of like a *fitting line* that considers all the widths.
- Currently there exist *gaps* between the rectangles. The contour should be a continuous curve that is gap-free.

Comment: why aren't you using `matplotlib.patches.Recatangle`?

Comment: is it intentional that the bottom one goes in and not out?

Comment: And I don't really see a question here, I see a list of requirements.  Please try to solve your own problem before bringing them here.

Comment: @tcaswell 1. I learned this and am not sure about `matplotlib.patches.Recatangle`, so didn't use it. 2. Yes, the code just ends there. 3. with no knowledge of fitting or graphs, this is the best that I can do. Sorry for the requirements, but I wish for at least some pointers or even key words. Only with those, I can kinda explore myself. =) Thanks!

Comment: you know where the corners of the rectangles are (as you drew them).  Just connect the dots to get a C(0) function, or for interpolation see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html